# Hang while running 'hello world' test in Fitnesse

Tags: c#, .net, fitnesse

I'm trying to evaluate Fitnesse to use with our .Net projects. I've been following the instructions laid out in Gojko Adzic's [Test Driven .NET Development
with FitNesse book](http://gojko.net/fitnesse/book/) and have fallen at the first hurdle. When I run the hello world test on page 19 fitnesse just hangs on the running tests screen.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

How do I go about debugging issues like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem. The syntax was incorrect defining the COMMAND_PATTERN was incorrect. I'd got %p on a separate line.